# Did Midorima forget to bring his lucky charm in the Winter Preliminaries?

Tags: kuroko-no-basket

As we all know, in *Kuroko no Basketball*, Midorimia usually brings along a lucky charm according to his horoscope for each day. For example, he once bought a bear with a fish in its mouth, as that was the lucky charm for the day. However, in the Winter Preliminaries against Seiho, I haven't seen him mentioning a lucky charm or holding a lucky charm, and I also couldn't see any lucky charm on the benches during the game.

[image]

Was this just that he forgot about it? Or was this a problem with the writers and producers, as they may have forgotten to include this crucial detail? I think this is quite unusual for Midorimia to not have a lucky charm during the game, as he has clearly demonstrated that he always had one.

**Note:** I noticed this during Season 2, Episode 30.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, he would have brought his lucky charm but it might not be shown in the anime because they may have assumed that it's Midorimia "thing" and it need not be highlighted again and again.